# How to cache api and assets in service worker in vue cli3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker, vue-cli

```
import { register } from 'register-service-worker'
import pwa from '@vue/cli-plugin-pwa'

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
// if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
console.log(pwa)
register(`${process.env.BASE_URL}service-worker.js`, {
ready () {
    console.log(
      'App is being served from cache by a service worker.\n'
    )
  },
  cached () {
    console.log('Content has been cached for offline use.')
  },
  updated () {
    console.log('New content is available; please refresh.')
  },
  offline () {
    console.log('No internet connection found. App is running in 
    offline mode.')
  },
  error (error) {
    console.error('Error during service worker registration:', error)
  }
})
}
```

This is my registerserviceworker.js. I tried to implement in this file but i am not able to add files and api in this.

Answer (score 7):

You have to use the "workboxOptions" inside the PWA Object of the vue.config.js.
Like this:

```
module.exports = {
    pwa: {
        [...]
        workboxOptions: {
            runtimeCaching: [{
                urlPattern: new RegExp('^https://yourpathtothe.api/'),
                handler: 'networkFirst',
                    options: {
                    networkTimeoutSeconds: 20,
                    cacheName: 'api-cache',
                    cacheableResponse: {
                        statuses: [0, 200],
                    },
                },
            }]
        }
    },
```

Comment: Can you please share the documentation for this?

Comment: PWA Ref in Vue-Cli 3 Docs: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/tree/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-plugin-pwa

Workbox dor Webpack Docs: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-webpack-plugin

Comment: what about this error :   vue-cli-service.cmd build

 ERROR  ValidationError: "runtimeCaching" is not a supported parameter.
ValidationError: "runtimeCaching" is not a supported parameter.